# Any coding tags missing code language setting for syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, tags, syntax-highlighting, formatting

From Meta Q&As like:

- [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)
- [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) and
- [Syntax highlighting for pyqgis](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/syntax-highlighting-for-pyqgis)

my understanding is that there should never be a need to manually override the syntax highlighting hint used when writing questions and answers on our site **unless the default syntax has not been set for a tag**.

I noticed today that this had not been set to Python for the [Shapely tag wiki](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/shapely/info) (see below) and so I spent a few seconds doing it.

To do this I used a **moderator privilege** and apparently this is the only way that it can be done - see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287065/215590) to [What reputation is needed to suggest language hints to be used for particular tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287063)

[image]

None of us want or should need to use manual overrides like:

`<!-- language: lang-py -->`

unless we are mixing code from several languages in our questions (which should be rare).

Are there **any** instances where you are finding that you have to go to the trouble of manually overriding the highlighting syntax chosen for one of our tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List of tags with syntax highlighting applied (after the question was posted):

- Bash: [bash](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash)
- C: [c](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)
- CSS: [css](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css)
- C++: [c++](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- default: [gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdal), [json](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json), [geojson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geojson), [topojson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topojson) (these do not have a more specific language syntax highlighting option available)
- HTML: [html5](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5)
- JavaScript: [leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaflet), [arcgis-javascript-api-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-2), [arcgis-javascript-api-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-3), [arcgis-javascript-api-4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api-4), [google-earth-engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine)
- Matlab: [matlab](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab)
- Python: [fiona](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiona), [geodjango](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geodjango), [shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapely), [pandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandas), [geopy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geopy), [pycsw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pycsw), [pyshp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyshp), [laspy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laspy)
- R: [r](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r), [ggplot2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2), [ggmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ggmap), [shiny](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiny), [sp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sp), [rgeos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rgeos), [rgdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rgdal), [lidr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lidr)
- regex: [regex](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex)
- SQL: [pgrouting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgrouting), [postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgis), [oracle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle), [spatialite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatialite), [expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression), [qgsexpression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgsexpression)
- XML: [xml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml)