# Code blocks are hard to distinguish from normal text

Tags: bug, design, code

Especially when syntax highlighting is off (e.g. because of the lack of proper tags like [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/344858/1)), code blocks are hard to distinguish from normal text, because the default background is already grayish:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a consequence of the [new post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/295232) or that it's a consequence of the responsive design which was rolled out a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I had not noticed this but, if I have understood your concern about it, then I do not think it is anything to worry about here because we always try to ensure that we have a code language setting for any code tags used on the site via [Any coding tags missing code language setting for syntax highlighting?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/any-coding-tags-missing-code-language-setting-for-syntax-highlighting)