# Syntax highlighting needed for expression tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting can be inferred from the question tag. It can be assumed, that for [expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) questions `sql` highlighting is appropriate in most of the cases, but this hint seems not to be present for this tag. [Only moderators have the privilege to change this](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/syntax-highlighting-for-pyqgis), so it would be nice if a moderator could take care of that.

Answer (score 5):

I've added it for you.

We are keen to track down any missing instances of needed syntax highlighting as you can see at [Any coding tags missing code language setting for syntax highlighting?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/any-coding-tags-missing-code-language-setting-for-syntax-highlighting)